# Take image from gallery and set to a CircleImageView

Tags: android, imageview, setbackground

So I'm inside a fragment and I want to take an image from gallery and set to a CircleImageView. I start an intent and correctly choose the image but on the onActivityResult the image is not setted. The default src image remains. This is the code

fragment_layout

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/photo"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                />
```

fragment class

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        view =  lf.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,container,false);
        mContext = getActivity();

        mProfilePhoto = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
        view.findViewById(R.id.profile_photo).setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.profile_photo:
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                try {
                    i.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), 0);
                }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            try {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("return-data");
                mProfilePhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

and the activity which implements this fragment has its onActivityResult whith just the call at super();

Also, after loading the image, will it be resized automatically to fit the circle image view? if not how should I do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I have experienced this problem. And I am using your library for all my projects.

```
if (requestCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
            if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST){
                Uri path = data.getData();
                try {
                    photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), path);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mProfilePhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);}}
```

Comment: what is photo used for?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I should used to setImageBitmap(photo) instead of setImageUri(path). I updated my answer.

Comment: İf My answer is working for you could you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Glide` with `ImageView` instead `CircleImageView` and set your `Bitmap` as a circle like follow

**Step 1.** Add on dependency

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

**Step 2.** Get bitmap from data and put on image view

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("return-data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
Glide.with(this)
        .load(stream.toByteArray())
        .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
        .into(imageView);
```

It's all

Comment: cannot resolve method asBitmap() and CircleTransform()

Answer (score 1):

---

> Why are you trying to get the data as bundle?Try to get as uri and set it to the circularimageview.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.profile_photo:
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), 0);   
                break;
        }

    }

  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK&&data!=null){
               Uri uri=data.getData();
                mProfilePhoto.setImageURI(uri);

        }
    }
```